# what is wrong with this enumeration procedure for the cantor set?

Tags: cantor-set

Consider the following procedure for constructing the cantor set $C$. Whenever I say *"$x$ is in $C$"*, read *"$[x,x]$ is in $C$"*.

Step 0. Take $I_0 = $ {$[0,1]$}, and let $n=0$

Step 1. For each interval $[a,b]$ in $I_n$, add $a$ and $b$ to $C$

Step 2. For each interval $[a,b]$ in $I_n$, add to $I_{n+1}$ the following intervals:

- $[a,a+(b-a)/3]$
- $[b-(b-a)/3, b]$

Step 3. Increment $n=n+1$, and Goto step 1

According to my understanding this should enumerate all elements of the cantor set, but then this is impossible because a diagonalization argument shows that the cantor set is uncountable, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This will enumerate the numbers $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{3^k}$$ for every $n\geqslant1$ and every finite sequence $(x_k)$ with values in $\{0,2\}$ and will omit all the numbers $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x_k}{3^k}$$ for every infinite sequence $(x_k)$ with values in $\{0,2\}$ such that $x_k=2$ for infinitely many $k$s and $x_k=0$ for infinitely many $k$s, although these are also in $C$.

Comment: More specifically, $1/4$ is in the Cantor set, but you don’t seem to have caught it in your enumeration.

Comment: There is more to the Cantor set than the endpoints of the intervals. The number $\frac14$ is in the Cantor set; it's not in the interior of any of the intervals you removed) but it's not an endpoint of any of those intervals either.

Comment: interesting... This may be a vague question but: how is it possible that a number is in the cantor set but is not generated by sequentially taking the points on those intervals, even though the cantor set is *defined* sequentially by those intervals?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer two of your questions at the same time:

1. Why does your enumeration procedure fall to the diagonalization argument?
2. Why is $\frac14$ in the Cantor set despite it not being the endpoint of any of the intervals used to construct the Cantor set?

$\frac14 = 0.\overline{02}_3$, and this very number can serve as an witness of the diagonalization argument, namely it is in the Cantor set (which can only consist of real numbers in $[0,1]$ with a ternary representation that does not have any '$1$'s, and it avoids all the elements in the sequence you asked for. Why so? Because it has infinitely many '$0$'s **and** '$2$'s, whereas each of the endpoints of the intervals, when expressed as ternary without any '$1$'s, must either end with "$\overline0$" or with "$\overline2$".

For a much simpler example of a set constructed as an intersection of closed intervals that includes a real number that is not an endpoint of any of those intervals, and moreover excludes the endpoints of all of those intervals:

> $\{0\} = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty [-\frac1k,\frac1k]$.

Comment: Well not really a witness for the **standard** diagonalization argument, but actually it is for a **general** diagonalization argument. Specifically, examine the sequence one element $x$ at a time, and each has finitely many '0's or finitely many '2's in its ternary representation without '1's, so append sufficiently many "02"s to the current ternary expression we are building to make it differ from $x$ at some digit. We of course have to prove that excluding '1's makes representations unique, and hence conclude that the final expression we built is distinct from each element in the sequence.

Answer (score -2):

Step 1 you have to put just b, or a. Depending what step you are. Look in that way you conting 0 a lot of times. But in that way, the number of element is not uncontable...